# Compiling Ogre3d application using the OgreAppWizard

Tags: c++, ogre

I have created an ogre application using the ogreappwizard. When I try to compile the solution I get an error saying that `Parameter "basePath" cannot be a relative path.`.

I followed all of the [instructions](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Setting+Up+An+Application+-+Visual+Studio), and have tried reinstalling both the Ogre SDK and the appwizard.

I am losing my head here. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into this issue myself. There seems to be a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/ogreappwizards/issues/detail?id=2) in the OgreAppWizard.

Until the bug is resolved, the fix is quite simple:

Go to `Project`->`Properties`->`Configuration Properties`->`Debugging`

Then simply remove the leading `"../"` from the path for `Command` and `Working Directory`.